# calendar date time portion became Negative

Tags: java, calendar

Here is the confusion:
firstly,i try to set the "time", and it shows conpletely fine on the debug

```
       time = Calendar.getInstance();
       time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.hour);
       time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.minutes);
       time.set(Calendar.YEAR, alarm.starttime.getYear());
       time.set(Calendar.MONTH, alarm.starttime.getMonth());
       time.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, alarm.starttime.getDay());
```

then i want to get the "time"

```
        timeHour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        timeMinute = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        timeYear = time.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        timeMonth = time.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
        timeDay = time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

through the debug,I find that once the time.get executed the value of "time" becomes to be totally different(Negative);if time is 7.7,2015 ,then it changes to 7.1,2015
this really drives me mad does someone can help me?

Comment: what is "Negative" here? and where is alarm object?

Comment: Please edit a post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as is this is unclear

Comment: @ Raman Shrivastava the "time" value of the Calendar object becomes negative (long value less than zero );the alarm object is right.the problem is why the calendar object's value changes when " timeHour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);" is executed